# Error in dat file Exception from IBM ILOG Concert Excel range is unknown

Tags: cplex, idataerrorinfo, 4d

I write a 4D array data for my model, and now it show an error like the title.
Anyone help me to fix it?

This is a part of the data file:
[dat file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH4xv.png)
And this is the data file:

[data demand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgNX6.png)
[data D&C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCGpb.png)

I try to find solution on internet but it not work

Answer (score 0):

For 4D see [read](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/read4Darray.mod) and [write](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/write4Darray.mod)

But for your specific concern ( indirect) see

[image]

[model](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/3Dindirect.mod):

```
{string} Variante=...;
int Station=...;
int AP=...;


 
float nb[1..AP,1..Station*card(Variante)]=...;


float b[s in Variante][m in 1..AP][p in 1..Station]=nb[m,1+ord(Variante,s)*Station+(p-1)];
 execute {
   writeln("b = ",b);
};
```

[data](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/3Dindirect.dat):

```
SheetConnection sheet("3Dindirect.xlsx");
Variante from SheetRead(sheet,"data!B12:D12");
Station from SheetRead(sheet,"data!B8");
AP from SheetRead(sheet,"data!B9");

nb from SheetRead(sheet,"data!B4:J5");
```

Comment: So i should fix mod file instead of the dat file?

Comment: Indeed. The .dat should fit the Excel file structure. The .mod would turn the 2D structure into 4D